# Make openlayers embed map

Tags: openlayers, google-maps

I'm trying to do some kind of embed map and i see the way Google maps works. For exaple Google maps creates a URL like below :

```
https://www.google.es/maps/@39.4379818,-0.4569777,17z
```

Where it takes the latitude, longitude and zoom of the map's view you're at this moment. And when you zoom or move those parametes change in real time. And if you open that link you go to the zone shown by the parameters in URL.

My questions are? How it's done? It can be done only using client side code?

Comment: The dynamic link (maintaining the zoom and coordianates ) is fairly simple to recreate using Leaflet [hash](https://github.com/mlevans/leaflet-hash).

Comment: I know the hash property http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp (window.location.hash), but i need for openlayers 3. Also google maps uses '@'... I don't know what they do. But thanks for your answer! =)

Comment: In that case you should take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627682/how-to-create-permalinks-with-openlayers-3). If you are looking for a solution on a specific platform (like OL3) it's good practice to explicitly mention it in the question.

Comment: You're right I forgot say openlayers 3 as patform! Thank you for all!